# ActiveRecord Use An array of arrays As Parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

I would like to form the following query:

```
SELECT tracked_points.* 
FROM tracked_points 
WHERE
(id = 87 AND zone_id = 457)
OR
(id = 88 AND zone_id = 457)
```

My input to the function will be a nested array of `[id, zone_id]`, something like:

`[[87, 457], [88, 457]]`

I tried a little trick I saw on the [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem site

```
arr = [[87, 457], [88, 457]]
TrackedPoint.where((["(id = ? AND zone_id = ?)"] * arr.size).join(" OR "), *arr)
```

but it doesn't like taking a nested array as an argument.

The solution I came up with just compiles a SQL string, but doesn't use any parameter sanitation of prepared statements:

```
matches = arr.map do |i|
  "(id = #{i[0]} AND zone_id = #{i[1]})"

TrackedPoint.where(matches.join(" OR ")
```

I have a feeling an answer is possible with squeel, but if there is a pure ActiveRecord answer I'm game to try that out as well.

- Rails 3.2.13
- ruby 1.9.3-p392

Comment: ActiveRecord is rather limited to create complex queries. Without any external add-ons like squeel I think You won't do any better than generating this string. Even if You will find some interesting better way doing it in SQL, You will still generate sequel string.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons Any idea how I might add parameter sanitizing to this approach?

Comment: Check out this method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote
I thin it should be available on connection object, so You should be able to access it like this: `TrackedPoint.connection.quote`.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons I can't find any examples of the syntax on how to use `quote`. Do you know how it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `flatten` the nested array first.

```
TrackedPoint.where((["(id = ? AND zone_id = ?)"] * arr.size).join(" OR "), *(arr.flatten))
```